# One Kubernetes pod gives more TPS than two or more

Tags: performance, kubernetes

I deploy container to AWS hosted kubernetes and run perf tests on it with https://github.com/wg/wrk

The application I deploy has an endpoint /person/all which just returns an integer

Here I have a deployment config

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helloworld
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helloworld
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helloworld
        image: alexey007gold/helloworld:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 2
            memory: 1G
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp-dir
          mountPath: "/tmp"
      volumes:
        - name: tmp-dir
          emptyDir:
            {}
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 59417
        runAsUser: 59417
```

and a service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld
  labels:
    app: helloworld
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: helloworld
```

Also I deploy a container to run tests from

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: wrk-job
  labels: 
    app: wrk-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 59417
        runAsUser: 59417
      volumes:
      - name: tmp-dir
        emptyDir:
          {}
      containers:
      - name: wrk-job
        image: skandyla/wrk:latest
        command: ["sleep"]
        args: ["2h"]
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "8G"
            cpu: "15"
          requests:
            memory: "8G"
            cpu: "15"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tmp-dir
          mountPath: "/tmp"
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Then I ssh into it with

```
kubectl exec -it wrk-job-n6b8x sh
```

and run the test

```
wrk -t500 -c500 -d10s http://helloworld:8080/person/all
```

For one pod I get around 70K requests/second. When I scale to 2 pods

```
kubectl scale deployment/helloworld --replicas=2
```

I get only half of that, while I'd expect it double.
Is anything wrong with my understanding how multi instance performance should work?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this question from the Kubernetes perspective.

Scaling your deployment will average the load between all pods. When you [scale your deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#scaling-a-deployment) from 1 to 2 pods, the load splits between them 50/50. So if the load is constant, the more replicas you have, the less average load will be distributed per pod. You can always increase the testing load if you want to achieve more TPS and see the results.

I think that the next natural step with this topic would be to get familiar with the [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/):

> Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of Pods in a
> replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set based
> on observed CPU utilization (or, with beta support, on some other,
> application-provided metrics).